# Messaging in xmatters through API call

Tags: xmatters

I am trying to message or send alert in Xmatters using API in postman. This call was successful and an Id also generated in response, but the message was not reached to the Targeted person.When I did it from UI the mail was sent to the targeted person.

Answer (score 1):

What was the endpoint of your API? Were you targeting an inbound integration endpoint (`api/integration/functions/UUID/triggers`), or the form endpoint (`/reapi/yyy-mm-ddd/forms/UUID/triggers`)? If you target the inbound integration endpoint, you will get a UUID returned while the form endpoint will return an event ID.
If an event was created, you will see an entry in the reports tab of the UI for that event and it will have any errors around notifying users.